# Python recognize digits in simple image with pytesseract

Tags: python, ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract

I'm trying to use pytesseract to recognize digital numbers from images as following:

[image: img]

i tried following code

```
text=pytesseract.image_to_string(img, lang='eng',
                config='--psm 13 --oem 3 -c tessedit_char_whitelist=0123456789')
print(text)
```

it gives me

> "ae"

I tried oem=1 and it's still the same.

for your reference my version is as follows:

```
pytesseract.get_tesseract_version()
```

> LooseVersion ('4.0.0-beta.1')

Any help would be appreciated, including alternative libraries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is a known issue - [Blacklist and whitelist unsupported with LSTM (4.0)](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/issues/751)

basically whitelist and blacklist does not work

one comment states

> ghost commented on Jul 20, 2018
>
> Use --oem 0 or -oem 0 and it works

i have no way to test this ATM but it is worth a try

4.1 version should have this fixed